# FTPClient unable to parse LIST response from Apache FTPServer

Tags: ftp, apache-commons-net, apache-mina, ftp-server

While trying to perform a `listFiles()` command using Apache Commons Net 3.3 FTPSClient against an Mina's Apache FTP Server parsing of the listing fails.

I've done some debugging and the `entries` attribute on `FTPListParseEngine` after reading the server list has entries formatted like this:

`[x­Ô[, 0ÐÿB÷0Hy, º.B4¡­ÓÇò, «b%-%Mp2s¹ ó6`

I wouldn't know if this is an encoding issue on the server side or the clients'

Any hint would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  It turns out that my FTP server supports compression. I was setting mode to "Z" (compressed) after logging in which seems to alter further transfers behaviour.

I'm assuming the library was trying to parse a compressed response as it would be plain.